# save twitter followers into MongoDb using tweepy

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, tweepy

I want to store the Twitter data in MongoDb using tweepy. I want to store it in the below format:

```
{
    "followee": 12345,
    "follower": 54321,
    "follower_Name": abcd
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: I suggest you at least show that you have tried to engage with the problem a little more than posting some JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python I would recommend:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

```
// Mongo shell
db.createCollection("tweeps")
db.tweeps.insert([{
    "followee": 12345,
    "follower": 54321,
    "follower_Name": abcd
}])

// Python
tweeps = db.tweeps
tweeps.insert_many([{
    "followed": 12345,
    "follower": 54321,
    "follower_Name": abcd
}])
```

Comment: Adjusted the answer for you @User123. Just change one to many and the parameter is an array.